# Vector multiplication with XOR in Matlab

Tags: matlab, xor

I have two binary matrices and I want to multiply them. But after multiplication when digits are added, I want it to perform Exclusive-OR (XOR) operation rather than normal addition.

Example:

```
a = (1 0)
b = (1 1)
c = a*b
```

I want my program to calculate this:

```
c = (1*1) xor (0*1)
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of xor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xor.html)? If so, please elaborate on your confusion.

Comment: Or maybe you want [`bitxor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitxor.html)? Your question is unclear.

Comment: You cannot define arrays as you did. You need to use square brackets: `a = [1 0];`.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the bits using `sum` and `mod` (this generalizes to more than two bits)

```
c = mod( sum( a.*b ), 2 )
```

Comment: Actually, without `sum`, `c = mod( a.*b, 2 )` is working in my case. This means matrix multiplication with `xor` not `addition`.